# How to put data from websocket on to amazon kinesis data stream without any code in between(just by using managed aws services)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, architecture, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to put data from a 3rd party websocket server onto an amazon kinesis data stream. But examples from aws illustrate that producer code is necessary. This websocket stream is highly unpredictable, there will be too much data in just a second and then there'll be not much data.

Proxying data from source websocket server using a script an aws creates a point of bottle neck. I do not want this to happen. Are there any services in aws that I can use to prevent using my own script? Just putting the data straight from source websocket server on to kinesis data stream.

I've read about Websocket API by aws and from what I've understood it is best for creating websocket servers and it is not a managed websocket client.